# Slick Slider Content only load when i click on slick-arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel, slick.js

I implement the Slick Slider it works perfect if i load the slider on page loads.
The issue is when i hide the slider div and show it on some click listener. it does not work until i click on Side arrows.
Any Solution ?
Here is my Code.

```
<div class="year-main">
        <h4>Year</h4>
        <div class="center year-listing">
          <div><a href="#" onClick="return show_price()">2012</a></div>
          <div><a href="#" onClick="return show_price()">2013</a></div>
          <div><a href="#" onClick="return show_price()">2014</a></div>
          <div><a href="#" onClick="return show_price()">2015</a></div>
          <div><a href="#" onClick="return show_price()">2016</a></div>
          <div><a href="#" onClick="return show_price()">2017</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is Javascript:

```
   $('.center').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        infinite: true,
        centerPadding: '60px',
        slidesToShow: 4,
        speed: 500,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                arrows: false,
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '40px',
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                arrows: false,
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '40px',
                slidesToShow: 1
            }
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Simply initiate the slider on that click event

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. i Tried but it only works when slider is initiate on page loads,

Comment: add a JSFiddle and I'll try to solve the problem for you

Comment: How can i add this ?

Comment: go to  https://jsfiddle.net/ and add your code there, make it work there as it works in your production environment, save and upload here your link

Comment: ok i will do it thanks ver much i will send you link